# Need Help writing a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, database, search

I have a database with customer information, orders, etc. I need to run a query that returns all customers who have not placed an order at all.

Relevant tables: login and orders

Relevant Columns: login.loginID, login.loginFirstName, login.loginLastName, login.loginEmailAddress AND orders.OrderuserID

So essentially - in psuedocode: compare table login, column loginID for matches in the orders table under orders.OrderUserID. If no match exists (as in no orders placed) then output the users First Name, Last Name and Email address.

I have been racking my brain but having some real issues with the language. I'm a big time N00B when it comes to SQL.

Comment: Let's see what you've tried as a first go around

Comment: I'm assuming i have to subset but I can't get past the select from statement...not sure where to begin actually. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I learn best by reverse engineering so seeing the right answer will help me understand how you arrived there. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please, consider always posting http://whathaveyoutried.com when posting questions. This help us know your background and shows that you are not a "code for me please" boy.

Comment: What I tried were so many variations that I literally got frustrated and deleted it. THanks for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select loginFirstName, loginLastName, loginEmailAddress 
from login
where loginID not in
    (select distinct OrderuserID from orders)
```

You can also do it with a left join:

```
select loginFirstName, loginLastName, loginEmailAddress 
from login left join orders on loginID = OrderuserID 
where OrderuserID is null
```

Not sure which will execute faster; give it a try. The first is easier to understand, IMHO.

EDIT: "select distinct" means "return me the set of unique values of the field". So, the subquery in the first SQL returns the set of users (their IDs) who do have orders. If a user has multiple orders, DISTINCT makes sure her ID is returned only once.

Comment: Join will be faster, sometimes by a very large margin.

Comment: Depending on the rusultset and table structure, a join can be much faster.

Comment: What is the function of the select distinct our of curiosity...the first was quicker to run btw

Comment: A join will be at least one order faster. It may be that the first runs faster with a small set, but the subquery will bite you as the tables grow.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it'll look like that:

```
      SELECT l.login_id
        FROM login l
   LEFT JOIN orders o
          ON l.login_id = o.login_id
       WHERE o.login_id IS NULL
```

The key is using LEFT JOIN with WHERE ... IS NULL condition. In other words, you specifically look for the rows in `login` table that don't have any information 'extended' within `orders` table.

That's just a general description, but I hope it should be helpful in your process of constructing the big query specific to your case. )

Comment: +1 for beeing the only one who bothers to write UPPERCASE when supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select *
from login l
left join orders o on l.loginId = o.OrderuserID
where o.OrderuserID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select login.loginFirstName, login.loginLastName, login.loginEmailAddress  
FROM login 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON login.loginID = orders.OrderuserID 
WHERE orders.OrderuserID IS NULL;
```

or something like that. I suspect the trick for a newer SQL user is the LEFT OUTER join. Without that specifier, a join will only return rows from the first table IF there are matches in the second. This way you get them all (and then filter out matches with the IS NULL phrase).

Answer (score 0):

Though you should try first yourself and you could search on google first :):) .
 Anyways you can use it in this way,

```
SELECT l.loginFirstName,l.loginLastName,
l.loginEmailAddress FROM login AS l LEFT JOIN orders as o 
ON l.loginID = o.OrderuserID where OrderuserID is NULL
```